# How to "honestly" calculate likelihood of 2D normal with small sample size?

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, t-distribution

I estimate covariances from data and want to calculate likelihood.

For 1D case I know - if the sample size is $<40$, I use Student's t-distribution to calculate likelihood of the data since my variance is estimated from data.

For 2D case I can easily use formula from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Likelihood_function , but, again, I estimate variances from data and the sample size is not that big! People use chi-squared even for small sample sizes (which means they are OK with normality assumption), but it is obviously wrong. How can I take into account "underestimation" of true variance in 2D case? Is "multivariate t distribution" required?

Comment: looks like yes: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/LaplacesDemon/versions/16.1.1/topics/dist.Multivariate.t with (df - 2) / (df) * covMatrix as covariance...

Comment: The likelihood does not have anything whatsoever to do with degrees of freedom, nor with estimates.  What, then, are you trying to ask about "underestimation"??

Comment: I have two models, both of them have 1D normal distribution underlying. I estimate variance from data. To understand to which model my data point belongs, I need to compare likelihoods under different models. Even if I know that my underlying distribution is normal, I use t-distribution to find the likelihood of data point under any of these 2 models since my sample size is small and variance estimated from the data.

Comment: That's not a valid approach.  The likelihood, according to a very widely accepted definition, is a function of the sample mean, the sample variance, the sample size, and the assumed Normal parameters.  Student t distributions play no role.  Is it possible you mean something unusual by "likelihood"?  Maybe it would help to explain the meaning in your post.

Comment: Sorry for the delay with answer...No, I just wanted to find the joint likelihood of datapoints from normal distribution with SD estimated from data. And I honestly don't understand why the mean of data follows t-distribution while, as you say, it has not effect on calculating of likelihood for points separately...

Comment: It is unusual for the mean of data to follow a Student t distribution (unless the data are drawn from a t distribution to begin with).  You seem to be confusing the distribution of a test statistic, such as a t statistic, with the likelihood function.  We have some good threads about this: search for "likelihood" and read some of the highest-voted ones.

Comment: @whuber oh now I see. I do not know why I had this misconception. Thanks a lot!